# getIndexInfo() not returning list of indexes in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have created a database with multiple indexes in mongodb. I basically want to retrieve the list of indexes through JDBC. I found that getIndexInfo() returns the list of indexes. But in the following code that I've implemented, getIndexInfo() doesn't return the list correctly, it instead returns a null list.

```
public static void index() {

  try {
    System.out.println("Connecting Database");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = client.getDB("emp_data");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("emp_details");
    String tableName = "emp_details";

    final String indexName = new StringBuilder (tableName).append ("_pk").toString ();
       System.out.println("Name : " + indexName);
    List<DBObject> indexes = collection.getIndexInfo ();
    for(DBObject index : indexes ) {
       System.out.println("Index : " + index.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("Out : " + indexes.size());

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  }
}
```

Does anybody know any reason as to why this issue may arise ?

Comment: This isn't JDBC but just the MongoDB driver. What are you comparing it to? Have you tried in the mongodb shell to see the same basic call returns something else?

Comment: Have a look in to this https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/list-indexes/#list-all-indexes-on-a-collection

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes i have tried in the mongodb shell with getIndexes() , it returns the indexes perfectly well. using getIndexInfo() for some reason is not returning the list of indexes.

Comment: Personally I would like to see exactly what you are executing in the shell so I can "spot the difference". You are connecting to a different database or choosing another collection ( possibly mispelled in the listing ) or something like that. The only reason you would receive "nothing" is because something in your code is pointing to the wrong thing.